# Why am I receiving an overflow error?

Tags: c#

So below is my code, I'm new to c# and the foreach loop, as I understand this shouldn't ever cause an overflow unless I'm missing something silly?

```
int[] testCopyArray = new int[10] { 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 6, 15, 7, 8, 11 };
int[] secondArray = new int[10];

Array.Copy(testCopyArray, secondArray, testCopyArray.Length);
Console.WriteLine("FirstArray Length: " + testCopyArray.Length + " Second Array Length: " + secondArray.Length);
foreach (int num in testCopyArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Array: " + testCopyArray[num-1] + " Second Array: " + secondArray[num-1]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: It is an overflow - he's iterating the values of testCopyArray and using them to index back in to testCopyArray and secondArray.  The 7th iteration is attempting to show the value of testCopyArray[15]., it holds 10 value (0 thru 9) and so 15 is an overflow.

Comment: @BrianRiley I'd argue that it's out of bounds, I can't see anything that is overflowing.

Comment: @Mathemats - fair enough

Comment: apologies, by overflow I meant out of bounds :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `testCopyArray[num-1]` (or `secondArray[num-1]`), you are accessing the element in the array whose index is `num-1`.

The `foreach` loop that you have will go through the items in the array. So the value of `num-1` would be `7, 3, 4, 0, 2, 5, 14, 6, 7, 10`.

So, you are trying to access `testCopyArray[14]` for example. And the array does not have an index `14`.

I think that what you intended to do is to loop through the valid indexes of the array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testCopyArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Array: " + testCopyArray[i] + " Second Array: " + secondArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I had misunderstood the foreach loop thinking the variable worked in place of the iterator.This makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You're using num like a counter - it's the actual item.

```
foreach (int num in testCopyArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestCopyArray Number: " + num);
        }
```

For what you were tying to do you'd need an index.

Answer (score 0):

num isn't an index into the array but rather the value. Once you hit 15 (index 6) it will go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach (int num in testCopyArray)` look will iterate thru the contents of that array.  When you use `num` in an expression (`testCopyArray[num-1]`) you eventually dereference element `testCopyArray[15-1]` which is out of bounds and causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a for loop instead of a foreach loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < testCopyArray.Length && i < secondArray.Length; i++)
 {
        Console.WriteLine("First Array: " + testCopyArray[i] + " Second Array: " + secondArray[i]);
 }
```